# scrollTop() doesn't work right on phone

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am using a function in which I call other function to load more posts. That function detects if I have scrolled to the bottom of the page.

```
if($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() > $(document).height() - 1) {
   //some ajax here
}
```

It works really good on web browser and even on phone when I debug it with Chromium dev tools and scroll it down with mouse. But the problem occurs when I scroll down via phone.

This is the console.log when I scroll with mouse.

```
doc  4466 // document height
scr + hei 4466 //scroll top + window height
scr  3952 //scroll top
```

And this is the console.log when I scroll with phone (slide over screen).

```
doc  4466
scr + hei 4410
scr  3896
```

So it is obvious that scroll top has a different value than when scrolled with mouse.

Can someone tell what went wrong?

Btw. I am using this meta tag: `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=0">`

Comment: Have you considered it could be related to the height of the mobile browser's addressbar?

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan yeah I did, and now that you mention it, that could be the case, but how to fix it? I could say -100 instead of -1, but that makes a total mess since it calls the funcion 100 times if I scroll it to the bottom.